# Strange errors when doing bundle install with Cramp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, gemfile, cramp

Here is a `Gemfile` of default Rails application.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Whei I run `bundle install` everything is intalled fine.

Now do

```
gem install cramp
```

It is being installed also without any troubles.

And finally include

```
gem 'cramp'
```

into `Gemfile`. From now on we have following results:

bundle install

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    cramp (>= 0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      activesupport (= 3.0.pre) x86-mingw32

    rails (= 4.1.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      railties (= 4.1.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
        activesupport (4.1.0)
```

bundle update

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "thor":
  In Gemfile:
    cramp (>= 0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      thor (~> 0.14.6) x86-mingw32

    rails (= 4.1.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      railties (= 4.1.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
        thor (0.19.1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    cramp (>= 0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      activesupport (= 3.0.pre) x86-mingw32

    rails (= 4.1.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      activesupport (4.1.0)
```

I did not specify a Cramp version so there must be used the same version as I installed with `gem install cramp`. But why `gem install` worked without any problems and bundle install has found some unresolved dependencies?

I am trying to do all this on Windows 7 + Ruby 2.0.0p451 + Rails 4.1.0
and on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with the same Ruby and Rails versions.

What I tried: I ran `bundle install` and `bundle update` on default `Gemfile`, then added `gem 'cramp'`, ran `bundle install` and `bundle update` again. Results you can see few lines above.

Comment: @SNEH PANDYA: Already did this before posting here, with no result.

Comment: Rename Gemfile.lock and do bundle install again..

Comment: @Sumit Munot: same result.

Comment: It seems "Cramp" gem might not support "Rails 4"..Can you please try it with rails 3...

Comment: Here is the git repo seems support for Rails->3+ only..https://github.com/lifo/cramp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Cramp is inactive from last 4 months and [it doesn't support](https://github.com/lifo/cramp) Rails 4

Here are some more alternatives for Cramp Gem

[Alternatives for Cramp Gem](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cramp)